# Среда разработки на node js с отладчиком

Tags: node.js

Какая есть среда разработки на node js приложений, где есть удобный отладчик, с пошаговым исполнением, просмотром содержимых переменных, консолью как это есть например в браузере хром?

Comment: Тысячи их: NetBeans, WebStorm, .... (продолжите список сами)

Comment: VS Code весьма хорош, имхо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) , ставить

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

а свои приложения запускать так

```
node-debug твоя.js
```

может не совсем то что имелось в термине "Среда разработки"

Comment: Этот вариант лучше всего, отладчик открывается сразу в хроме. Хотя и не такой удобный как для клиентского кода.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй WebStorm. Там вроде как даже свой плагин в браузер ставится.